# How to play audio only ads using Google IMA HTML5

Tags: google-ad-manager, google-ima

I'm using Google IMA HTML5 SDK to display audio only ads on my website,
I followed this tutorial:
https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/html5/client-side
But it ends up showing a video player with black screen and playing the audio in the background, what I want to do is to show audio player instead of the video one.

As they claim here:
https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/html5/client-side/compatibility

The HTML5 SDK supports audio only content.

Answer (score 1):

As detailed [here](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/html5/client-side/audio#use_of_an_audio_tag_for_content_playback) :

> The constructor for AdDisplayContainer takes a second argument named
> videoElement which IMA tracks as the content player. This argument
> accepts both a  or  tag. For audio content and ads, this
> guide recommends using an  tag to construct an
> AdDisplayContainer. If you have video content, you can use a 
> tag for showing a mix of audio and video ads...

Full guide [here](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/html5/client-side/audio).